Literature on network theory and/or systems theory
I am interested in learning about the network theory and the systems theory, especially from the social and cognitive standpoints, but I've been struggling to find any decent textbooks about it.
I would be very thankful for some recommendations or for guidance on where to look for such books in the future.
Please forgive me if this isn't the right forum for such questions.

Book recommendation questions are sometimes tolerated here, but this question is both particularly broad and asking for personal opinion, so not a good fit here.

The late sociologist Luhmann dedicated his career to think and write about systems. Among other things, he was renowned for a deep understanding of previous theories and how they fit together, so his works (like Introduction to Systems Theory) may be a good place to start.
I'm unsure if he's written specifically about networks much.
